# Import HSM-protected keys to Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

We are trying to Import HSM-protected keys to Azure Key Vault (BYOK)....
We could generate a KEK and download the KEK public key

We have the following queries

1. We are trying out SoftHSM on Windows 10 machine to generate HSM/Target Key ...Can we import softhsm target key to Azure Key Vault..
2. Can you please let us know the steps to achieve the above?

any suggestions on this?
Are we on the right track ..any guidance is appreciated

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: Hi @ShivaDarshan, is there any update? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to support SoftHSM, there are the supported HSMs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/hsm-protected-keys-byok#supported-hsms).

[image]